# How to change leftBarbuttonItem title?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I want to change leftBarButton title. I've tried this

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target:nil
                                action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
```

but it brings changes like

[image]

But I want it like

[image]

How it can be possible?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: @jcesar: You see the arrow which is default backBarButtonItem. But in 2nd view it is "<Rearrange" means title of the first page but I need it like this "<Back"

Comment: use an image with "< Back" Text...it is best way for it

Comment: but I'm using default navigationBar. How it can be uses @Parvendra Sing:

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(someMethod)];     Like this

Comment: You can also just create a UIButton in way you want(using an arrow image and title) and create a UIBarButtonItem using that button.

Comment: Use Luke Fletcher answer, you have to set the backBarButtonItem, not the leftBarButtonItem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may helpful for you

```
      UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backAction:)];
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

Comment: No its working like code that I've posted in my question . but thanks for reply.

Comment: For this get back to that controller and in which you are pushing that viewcontroller and write before pushing that  self.title = @"Back";

Answer (score 3):

From the view controller (ViewController1) that is pushing the next view controller (ViewController2), you need to set the backBarButtonItem.

```
@implementation ViewController1

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}
```

Comment: Just to add for clarity, the `backBarButtonItem` for a `UIViewController` `UINavigationItem` is not the button you will see when that view controller is on the screen, but instead when another one is pushed on top of it and it is the second to top-most one in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally normal that you don't see any arrow in your back button. That's because you're creating a new bar button that you set its title and its style. But the style you've set for your bar button item won't give you what you wanted.

I suppose that you're using `UINavigationController` to navigate. If it's the case, you need to get a reference to **navigationBar** that `UINavigationController` displays on the screen. Then, you'll be able to change its color via tint color property. So,

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

would do what you want to achieve. Here is the image i obtained using the code i mentioned above. [image]

If you're not using `UINavigationController`, the simplest solution is to provide an image for your back button which has already an arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `backBarButtonItem` instead of `leftBarButtonItem`. And remember to set it not in current view controller (where you wish it to be displayed) but in parent one (to which this button will return you).

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code and

```
  UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
  UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackBtn.png"]  ;  
  [backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
  [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
  backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 30);  
  UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;  
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

and for going to back use this method .

```
  -(void)goback
    {
       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;

- (IBAction)backAction:(id)sender
{
MainMenuViewController *mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainMenuViewController animated:YES];
}
```